# Bar plots with small x-values

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a bar chart with really small x-increments. I used this code:

```
    \begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=30, minor y tick num = 5, area style,]
    \addplot+[ybar interval,mark=no] plot coordinates { (0.13, 15) (0.191, 17) (0.252, 26) (0.313, 3) 
    (0.374, 3) (0.435, 3) (0.496, 5) (0.56, 0)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Which produced this picture:

[image]

The problem is that the numbers that appear under the x-axis have nothing to do with the numbers I want to plot. I think the bars are in place, it's just that the numbers that show up are 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, etc. but my plot starts at 0.13 and has increments of 0.061 . I would like *those* values to appear (i.e. 0.13, 0.191, 0.252, and so on) instead.
I have tried defining `xmin` and `xmax` values and definig the xbar interval, but nothing seems to work. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want you just need to add `xtick=data` to the `axis` options. To show more than two decimal places you need in addition to adapt the `x tick label style`. For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```latex
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=0,
        ymax=30,
        % show ticks at the data points
        xtick=data,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % (adapt the tick label style to see all three decimal digits)
        x tick label style={
            rotate=90,
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                precision=3,
                zerofill,
        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        minor y tick num = 5,
        area style,
    ]
        \addplot+[ybar interval]  coordinates {
            (0.13,15) (0.191,17) (0.252,26) (0.313,3)
            (0.374,3) (0.435,3)  (0.496,5)  (0.56,0)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]